# Optimize a numpy ndarray indexing operation

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy operation that looks like the following:

```
 for i in range(i_max):
    for j in range(j_max):
        r[i, j, x[i, j], y[i, j]] = c[i, j]
```

where `x`, `y` and `c` have the same shape.

Is it possible to use numpy's advanced indexing to speed this operation up?

I tried using:

```
i = numpy.arange(i_max)
j = numpy.arange(j_max)
r[i, j, x, y] = c
```

However, I didn't get the result I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexing arrays need to be [broadcastable](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for this to work. The only change needed is to add an axis to the first index `i` to match the shape with the rest. The quick way to accomplish this is by indexing with `None` (which is equivalent to `numpy.newaxis`):

```
i = numpy.arange(i_max)
j = numpy.arange(j_max)
r[i[:,None], j, x, y] = c
```

Comment: In other tests I've found that flattened indexing tends to be faster, even taking into account the time needed to generate the flat index.  But your `[:,None]` is the key to both approaches.  Your version is also clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -

```
d0,d1,d2,d3 = r.shape
np.put(r,np.arange(i_max)[:,None]*d1*d2*d3 + np.arange(j_max)*d2*d3 + x*d3 +y,c)
```

---

**Benchmarking and verification**

Define functions -

```
def linear_indx(r,x,y,c,i_max,j_max):
    d0,d1,d2,d3 = r.shape
    np.put(r,np.arange(i_max)[:,None]*d1*d2*d3 + np.arange(j_max)*d2*d3 + x*d3 +y,c)
    return r

def org_app(r,x,y,c,i_max,j_max):
    for i in range(i_max):
        for j in range(j_max):
            r[i, j, x[i,j], y[i,j]] = c[i,j]
    return r
```

Setup input arrays and benchmark -

```
In [134]: # Setup input arrays
     ...: i_max = 40
     ...: j_max = 50
     ...: D0 = 60
     ...: D1 = 70
     ...: N = 80
     ...: 
     ...: r = np.zeros((D0,D1,N,N))
     ...: c = np.random.rand(i_max,j_max)
     ...: 
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,N,(i_max,j_max))
     ...: y = np.random.randint(0,N,(i_max,j_max))
     ...: 

In [135]: # Make copies for testing, as both functions make in-situ changes
     ...: r1 = r.copy()
     ...: r2 = r.copy()
     ...: 

In [136]: # Verify results by comparing with original loopy approach
     ...: np.allclose(linear_indx(r1,x,y,c,i_max,j_max),org_app(r2,x,y,c,i_max,j_max))
Out[136]: True

In [137]: # Make copies for testing, as both functions make in-situ changes
     ...: r1 = r.copy()
     ...: r2 = r.copy()
     ...: 

In [138]: %timeit linear_indx(r1,x,y,c,i_max,j_max)
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop

In [139]: %timeit org_app(r2,x,y,c,i_max,j_max)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.25 ms per loop
```

Comment: Would `np.ravel_multi_index` simplify this index generation?

Comment: @hpaulj That might, haven't used that function that much though. I guess I prefer the crude way of calculating this :)